# Return records of one value and not in other values

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for asking such simple question but here I am getting trouble while getting records from single table, my table contains records which have different values in `prod_code` for similar `product_number`. I want records of such `product_number` which have specific `prod_code`, and not others. For example from below table I need a records which have only `prod_code` with value `CIOFB1` and not `CIOFB2`, `CIOFB2`.

| product_number | prod_code |
| --- | --- |
| A1NU0001093 | CIOFB1 |
| A1NU0001093 | CIOFB2 |
| A1NU0001093 | CIOFB3 |
| A1NU0001094 | CIOFB1 |
| A1NU0001094 | CIOFB2 |
| A1NU0001094 | CIOFB3 |
| A1NU0001095 | CIOFB1 |
| A1NU0001096 | CIOFB1 |
| A1NU0001096 | CIOFB2 |
| A1NU0001096 | CIOFB3 |

I tried creating this query but not getting the records as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM product_number WHERE prod_code= 'CIOFB1'
AND prod_code NOT IN ('CIOFB2', 'CIOFB3') ;
```

output:

```
A1NU0001095   CIOFB1
```

As other `product_number` do have all the `prod_code`

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: expected o/p according to above query : A1NU0001095 CIOFB1

Comment: you could simply select count(*) and group by product_number and then check if count is not > 1

Comment: You want all rows or just the matching rows or just the product? If I add a row A1NU0001095 CIOFB4, do you want to show that row, because the conditions for the product are met? Or don't show it, because CIOFB4 is not one of the desired codes? Or does it suffice to just show A1NU0001095 without its codes? (For the latter you should use conditional aggregation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE prod_code = 'CIOFB1' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.product_number = t1.product_number AND
                        t2.prod_code IN ('CIOFB2', 'CIOFB3'));
```

The above query says to retain any product's record having a `prod_code` of `CIOFB1`, which product simultaneously does *not* have `prod_code` values of `CIOFB2` or `CIOFB3`.

Comment: @MayurKandalkar [The query is working with your sample data in this demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ac0225565ef4966f47249c678610de7).

Comment: @FlashThunder I disagree with your comment in every way.  The query I have offered above can easily be tuned using an index on `(product_number, prod_code)`.  Aggregation as you suggest is an approach, but it is not at all clear that it would be performant than my answer.  Also: The OP wants to get back the entire rows.  Your aggregation suggestion would _not_ do that without an additional bulky subquery.

Comment: @FlashThunder Are we even talking about the same question here?  Your suggested query doesn't even filter on `prod_code` anywhere.  How can it be correct?